# How to add a new node inside an existing node?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to create a new node inside an existing node. the other codes that i tried just added the infos inside Mariot. Im trying to put node inside Mariot "Guest" then autoID then the info.

- hotels

  - Mariot
  - Adress: ########
  - Contact: ########
  - Email: ########
  - uniqueID: ########

I want to put another node inside Mariot which is "Guests"

Below is the code that i tried.

```
@IBAction func acceptBtn(_ sender: Any) {
Database.database().reference().child("hotels").queryOrdered(byChild: 
"uniqueID").queryEqual(toValue: requestID).observe(.childAdded) {
(snapshot) in

snapshot.ref.updateChildValues(["email":email, "contact":contact])
}
}
```

I was hoping it would look like this.

- hotels

  - Mariot
  - Adress: ########
  - Contact: ########
  - Email: ########
  - uniqueID: ########
  - Guests

    - (AutoID)
    - Email: ########
    - Contact: ########
    - (AutoID)
    - Email: ########
    - Contact: ########
    - (AutoID)
    - Email: ########
    - Contact: ########

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new value under a child node:

```
ref.updateChildValues(["guest/email":email, "guest/contact":contact])
```

If you also want an auto-ID in there:

```
let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
ref.updateChildValues(["guest/\(key)/email":email, "guest/\(key)/contact":contact])
```

But I'm not sure if you actually need to use `updateChildValues` here. You might also be able to simple do:

```
ref.childByAutoId().setValue(["email":email, "contact":contact])
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. but im getting an error when im using ref "use of unresolved identifier 'ref'. I need to put an autoID because if i dont. it will just overlap the previous info.

Comment: `ref` in the above is meant to be a [`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference) to whatever location you want to add the data under. It could just be `snapshot.ref` like in your code, or something else that may be more fitting.

Comment: My second and third snippet both show how to use auto-IDs.